# map showing wrong locations on map in codeigniter view index page

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps

hello i am using javascript in codeigniter for display pickers on map , my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$jsItems = array();
foreach($all as $item) {
    $jsItems[] = array(
        'title' => $item->studio_name,
        'lat' => $item->latitude,
        'lng' => $item->longitude,
        'description' => $item->address
    );}
echo 'var markers = '.json_encode($jsItems).';';?>
```

i am getting latitude longitude value from databse and display into map with pickers

```
window.onload = function () {
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var lat_lng = new Array();
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var data = markers[i]
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatlng,
map: map,
title: data.title
});
latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
(function (marker, data) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
})(marker, data);
}
map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

}



 </script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDROYAx0XxInepo42-zs3qrnU-40ER70QI"
    async defer></script>
```

this is my javascript code , i used google map , and it works better on other page but not work in codeigniter index page

Answer (score 0):

Just try like below code:

Please avoid script, you just directly write code in controller itself like below:

```
$config['center'] = '13.038433, 80.253362';
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '13.038433, 80.253362';
$marker['ondragend'] = 'showCoords(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());';
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
$datas['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
$this->template['middle'] = $this->load->view ($this->middle = 'pages/your_page',$datas, true);
```

please collect all the lat & log values in an array, then pass it into either foreach or forloop. Inside that try the above code.